# Analog amplifier circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, transistors, amplifier, resistors, analog

I've the following analog amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJTYdn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Vin is the input voltage of the amplifier and the V- system and the V+ system are the two points where I can controll the motor with the amplifier.

The questions I've are:

1. Has this amplifier a specific name?;
2. I think that the resistor R1 is a resistor to limit the current, but how does it do that?;
3. I think that R2 is a resistor to controll the voltage at the input of the voltage follower, but I can I caluclate that volateg?

Comment: seems to be a homework question. You should at least try to come to a solution yourself and tell us where you are stuck/ what you do not understand.

Comment: @SirSy It isn't a homework question. And I set my thoughts in the question (like that I think that R1 is a resistor to limit the current).

Comment: It is a Darlington transistor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has this amplifier a specific name?

It's a voltage controlled current sink. Vin is a demand voltage and the transistors turn on sufficiently to take a current through the load that equals \$I_{LOAD}\times R_2\$.

> I think that the resistor R1 is a resistor to limit the current, but
>   how does it do that?

That is what resistors do - if you apply a voltage across tthem they restrict the current as per ohms law. R1 is probably needed to restrict the base current into T2 should the motor (say) become stalled.

> I think that R2 is a resistor to controll the voltage at the input of
>   the voltage follower

Answered above.